# How do I create a complete disk mirror in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid, raid-1

I'm trying to mirror a *full* Disk in Windows Server 2008, however I don't see any options to mirror a full Disk, only Volumes.

Both disks are the same brand, size and are configured as Dynamic Disks, and the "spare" disk is unallocated. The "active" disk is the boot disk, and contains the 100mb "System Reserved" partition as well as the C: Volume. There are no other disk or partition used on the server.

I guess what I would want is a true raid1 image, where the disk used for mirroring could be booted if there was a problem with the main disk.

When I right-click on the disk I want to mirror, everything is greyed out but "Properties" and "Help".

How can I make a Disk Mirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do full disk mirrors using Windows Server, you can only do volume mirrors.

To do a full disk mirror, you will require hardware RAID controller.

Comment: I guess that settles it.

Comment: Not the answer you were after I'm guessing! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You just need to configure some specific parameters using diskpart and bcdedit. Check it out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951985

Answer (score 1):

You can Mirror your full disk (also disk that windows is installed on it).
see the documentation below (written by Microsoft):

[Configuring Disk Mirroring for Windows Server 2008 R2.docx](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23476)